# Is it possible to improve the performance of query with distinct?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is following query:

```
        "SELECT DISTINCT LEVEL, ID, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5" +
        " FROM custom_table +
        " WHERE fromDate=:startDate 
        " AND toDate=:endDate, 
        " AND AccountIds=[ :accountIds ]
        " AND LEVEL IN (:Levels)"
```

Some columns of the table (exclude dates and other non-important columns for us):

```
ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
LEVEL INTEGER,
R1 VARCHAR(50),
R2 VARCHAR(50),
R3 VARCHAR(50),
R4 VARCHAR(50),
R5 VARCHAR(50)
```

Simple data:

```
ID,LEVEL,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5
id1,1,TOTAL,null,null,null,null
id1,2,TOTAL,A,null,null,null
id1,2,TOTAL,B,null,null,null
id2,1,TOTAL,null,null,null,null
id2,2,TOTAL,A,null,null,null
id2,3,TOTAL,B,C,null,null
```

Current query is running more than 1s, usually it returns between 100 and 1000 records, I want to improve the performance of this query. I have tried to rewrite it with `GROUP BY` clause but it is overkill because there are no aggregation and it is redundant, I think.

Maybe there are ways to improve this query to fetch data a bit faster? I hope I've provided enough information here. Database is custom, NO_SQL giant under the hood but syntax of our database bridge is very similar to MySQL.

Comment: If your syntax is similar to MySql (and presumably ansi SQL) that probably won't translate to applying MySql performance tuning advice. Usually the best improvements in performance will come from suitable index(es).

Comment: share your query execution plan as well as indexes on that table.also what is "AccountIds"? you didn;t show it in your table structure

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: Are you really doing `=` tests on start and end dates?

Comment: Show us a simple query; square brackets are not allowed in MySQL:  `AND AccountIds=[ :accountIds ]`.

Comment: Have you considered restructuring your database design?

Answer (score 1):

You would seem to want an index on:  `(fromDate, toDate, accountId, levels)`.

The first three columns are all used for `=` comparisons, so they can be in any order.